# json object shows value 1

Tags: javascript, json

I am storing a json object in json array and assign it to another main json object, but when I print the value of main json object it display 1. Below is the code.

```
var jsonMainObject= {};
var jsonArray= [];

for(var j=0;j<cu.receivedData.length;j++) {
jsonMainObject["company"] = jsonArray.push(cu.receivedData[j].company);
}

console.log(jsonMainObject)
```

Below is the output

```
{ company: 1 }
```

But it should show the array. when i print jsonArray it shows the array of object, but when I console the output of jsonMainObject it displays the above output.

Comment: You need to provide more code/context. What does the `cu.receivedData` variable look like. What about the `jsonArray` variable?

Comment: Also, JSON is just a format for representing a javascript object. So, there is no such thing as a "JSON Object" per se. There are objects in javascript, and javascript objects represented in JSON (which is ultimately just a string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `push` method returns the new length of the array. See **[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)**. I guess you should use:

```
jsonMainObject["company"].push(valueToPush)
```

or use `concat` (**[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)**)

```
jsonMainObject["company"] = jsonMainObject["company"].concat(valueToConcat)
```

Comment: It is not a problem that `jsonMainObject` is an object, as it seems you want to push to `jsonMainObject["company"]`, that can be by the way written `jsonMainObject.company`. You might need to initialize the array though: `jsonMainObject.company = [];`

Comment: Thanks Michael by intialization it works. jsonMainObject["company"] = [];

Comment: Glad you sorted this out!

Answer (score 1):

There is no JSON at all here. JSON is a text format for representing data. What you have is a JavaScript object with a JavaScript array.

You are trying to put the array in the object at the same time as putting items in the array. The [`push` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) doesn't return the array that it was called on, it returns the length of the array. The `company` property will end up containing the length of the `receivedData` array.

You can put the array in the object from start:

```
var arr = [];
var mainObject = { company: arr };

for(var j = 0; j < cu.receivedData.length; j++) {
  arr.push(cu.receivedData[j].company);
}

console.log(mainObject);
```